# how to filter RDD map in Scala by elements not in tuple

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter

I have a word count example. If I wanted to filter out one common word I can do like this, where wordList is a tuple:

```
val filterWords = wordList.filter(x => x != "to")
```

But it's more useful to create a list of words to filter on:

```
val filterWords = ("a", "to", "the", "of", "I", "you")
```

How do you use that in the filter above? Or, how can I do like this, which is done in SQL?

```
where wordList not in ("a", "to", "the", "of", "I", "you")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val filterWords = Set("a", "to", "the", "of", "I", "you")

wordList.filterNot(filterWords.contains(_))
```

`filterWords.contains` will return true if and only if the element of `wordList` under consideration is in `filterWords`.  `filterNot` will pass through the elements for which the `contains` call returns false.

Comment: Ah. Yes, set is better than List

Comment: Just `filterWords.contains` three characters less and do not need to use the horrendous underscore syntax. Or even better, just pass the set since it is already a function, saving you from creating a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

What you created is a tuple not a list.

```
val filterWords = List("a", "to", "the", "of", "I", "you")
```

Then you can use

```
wordlist.filter(x => filterwords.contains(x))
```

Also have a look at the full [api of List](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#contains[A1%3E:A](elem:A1):Boolean)